# comando ping IPs

Tags: batch

Preciso fazer uma `.bat` que ao ser executada inicie o comando de `ping`.

Porém preciso que "ping" vários IPs automaticamente e no caso de em um determinado IP não responder, que ela apresente uma mensagem e logo depois peça para pressionar uma tecla para continuar e assim continue pingando até o último IP.

Até o momento consegui isso:

```
echo off
t
cls
color 1f
title APLICATIVO PARA GERENCIAMENTO DE REDES

:menu
time /t
date /t 

echo     ______________________________________________      
echo.                           
echo         SELECIONE UMA DAS OPCOES ABAIXO      
echo.                           
echo.                           
echo            (1) EXIBIR IP (simples)          
echo            (2) EXIBIR IP (completo)
echo            (3) EXCUTAR PING                
echo     ______________________________________________
echo.
echo.

set /p op= DIGITE UMA OPCAO 

if %op% equ 1 goto 1
if %op% equ 2 goto 2
if %op% equ 3 goto 3

:1 

ipconfig 
time /t >> c:\relatorio.txt
date /t >> c:\relatorio.txt
ipconfig >> c:\relatorio.txt

goto menu

:2

ipconfig /all
time /t >> c:\relatorio.txt
date /t >> c:\relatorio.txt
ipconfig /all >> c:\relatorio.txt


goto menu

:3

echo Digite o IP
set /p ip =
echo Qual o numero requisições?
set /p num = 

if "%num%"  == "0" ( 
ping -t %ip%
pause
) else (

ping %ip%
echo.
echo Fim do comando ping!
pause
)

goto menu
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOpt, pode focar na sua duvida?, a onde não esta conseguindo seguir em diante ?, fica mais fácil, e é mais compreensivo se você colocar o ponto onde você "travou", o titulo pode ser melhorado também !

Answer (score 2):

se for só ips eu faço assim:

procura termo "100%" onde no retorno do ping é "100% de falha"

```
ping x.x.x.x | find "100%"
if "%errorlevel%" equ "0" echo FALHOU
```

Comment: No caso dele ele pede para pressionar uma tecla se não responder, então com o comando acima substituindo o 'echo FALHOU' por 'pause'